# Counter counter

Tags: code-golf, string

In typography, a [counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_%28typography%29) is the area of a letter that is entirely or partially enclosed by a letter form or a symbol. A closed counter is a counter that is entirely enclosed by a letter form or symbol. You must write a program takes a string as input and prints the total number of closed counters in the text.

Your input:

- May be a command line input, or from STDIN, but you must specify which.
- Will consist entirely of the printable ASCII characters, meaning all ASCII values between 32 and 126 inclusive. This does include spaces. [More information.](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Now, this does vary slightly between fonts. For example, the font you're reading this in considers 'g' to have one closed counter, whereas the google font has 'g' with two closed counters. So that this is not an issue, here are the official number of closed counters per character.

All the symbols with no closed counters:

```
 !"'()*+,-./12357:;<=>?CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`cfhijklmnrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Note that this includes space.

Here are all the symbols with one closed counter:

```
#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq
```

And here are all the symbols with 2 closed counters:

```
$%&8B
```

And last but not least, here are some sample inputs and outputs.

`Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf` should print  `13`

`4 8 15 16 23 42` should print `5`

`All your base are belong to us` should print `12`

`Standard loopholes apply` should print `12`

`Shortest answer in bytes is the winner!` should print `8`

Comment: Two answers have submitted functions instead of full programs. While that is allowed by default, your wording suggests otherwise. Could you clarify?

Comment: Would you mind disclosing which going you used to count the counters?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'm not sure if I understand what you mean.

Comment: None of the fonts I'm viewing the question in corresponds to the counts you have given. E.g. in the browser, the zero has a diagonal slash through it, giving two counters. The font in the android app doesn't, but here the `g` has two closed counters. Did you determine the counters based on any particular font?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I just used whichever font came up when I wrote the question. (In the output, not the source) I guess I assumed that everybody is seeing the same font, but apparently they're not. Maybe it's a location thing?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem 'g' has 1; though where listed in code, `g` has 2. Slightly confusing to read, but I don't think it's different by location.

Comment: Doesn't `0` have 2 closed counters in certain fonts, especially many monospace fonts?

Comment: So what does it vary by? OS? Browser? I wrote this on Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem It varies by formatting. You used code markup for posting which letters. Look at your question. The monospaced `g` and `0` have 2 closed counters, which is confusing people.

Comment: @mbomb007 but on my computer, both g and 0 have 1 closed counter, even with the formatting.

Comment: Then I think you're in the minority, but since you defined the sets, it's fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Pyth, 31 bytes

```
sm@tjC"cúÁ-ÈN%³rØ|­"3Cdz
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%40tjC%22c%C3%BA%C3%81-%C2%85%15%C3%88%17N%25%C2%91%C2%B3%C2%9Cr%C3%98%1F%C2%87%7C%C2%AD%223Cdz&input=Programming%20Puzzles%20and%20Code-Golf&debug=0)

Note that the code may not be displayed properly due to the use of non-ASCII characters. The correct code is at the link.

I made a lookup table of the output desired for each input character, rotated it by 32 to make use of Pyth's modular indexing, stuck a 1 at the beginning, and interpreted it as a base 3 number, giving the number `2229617581140564569750295263480330834137283757`. I then converted this number to base 256 and converted it to a string, which is the string used in the answer.

Answer (score 28):

### Python 3, 63

```python
print(sum(map(input().count,"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq$%&8B$%&8B")))
```

A straightforward approach. Iterates over each character with a closed counter, summing the number of occurrences, doing so twice for characters with two closed counters. It would be the same length to instead write

```python
"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq"+"$%&8B"*2
```

Python 3 is needed to avoid `raw_input`.

Answer (score 12):

## CJam, <s>41</s> <s>39</s> <s>37</s> 34 bytes

```
"$%&8Badopq#0469@Rbeg"_A<eu+qfe=1b
```

*Thanks to @jimmy23013 for golfing off 3 bytes!*

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%24%25%268Badopq%230469%40Rbeg%22_A%3Ceu%2Bqfe%3D1b&input=4%208%2015%2016%2023%2042)

#### How it works

```
"$%&8Badopq#0469@Rbeg"             e# Push that string.
                      _A<          e# Retrieve the first 10 characters.
                         eu+       e# Convert to uppercase and append.
                                   e# This pushes "$%&8Badopq#0469@Rbeg$%&8BADOPQ".
                            q      e# Read from STDIN.
                             fe=   e# Count the occurrences of each character. 
                                1b e# Base 1 conversion (sum).
```

Comment: `"$%&8Badopq#0469@Rbeg"_A<eu+`.

Comment: @jimmy23013: I had tried a few variations of `eu` and `el`, but I never found that. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## sed, 51

With golfing help from @manatwork and @TobySpeight:

```
s/[$%&8B]/oo/g
s/[^#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq]//g
s/./1/g
```

Input from STDIN.  With [this meta-question in mind](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary), the output is in unary:

```
$ echo 'Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf
4 8 15 16 23 42
All your base are belong to us
Standard loopholes apply
Shortest answer in bytes is the winner!' | sed -f countercounter.sed
1111111111111
11111
111111111111
111111111111
11111111
$
```

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, 41

```
$_=y/#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq//+y/$%&8B//*2
```

`41` characters +1 for the `-p` flag.

This uses [y///](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) to count the characters.

```
echo 'Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf' | perl -pe'$_=y/#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq//+y/$%&8B//*2'
```

Answer (score 6):

## K, <s>54</s> <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```
+//(30#"$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq"=)'
```

Cut off 5 bytes thanks to @JohnE!

### Older version:

```
f:+/(#&"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq$%&8B$%&8B"=)'
```

### Original:

```
f:+/{2-(5="$%&8B"?x;20="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq"?x;0)?0}'
```

Comment: The `#&` inside the parens could just as easily be `+/`, which means you could go further with `+//"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq$%&8B$%&8B"=\:`. Finally, it's not necessary to have the `f:` since the function can be used in tacit form. That would bring you down to 38!

Comment: Unfortunately the trick a few other solutions have employed to compact the lookup table comes out dead even with the current 38 byte solution: `+//(30#"$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq")=\:`. This may be the best we can do.

Comment: haha, no sooner did I post that than I saved a character: `+//(30#"$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq"=)'`

Answer (score 6):

## GNU APL, 39 bytes

```
+/⌈20÷⍨26-'$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq'⍳⍞
```

Try it online in [GNU APL.js](http://baruchel.hd.free.fr/apps/apl/#code=%2B%2F%E2%8C%8820%C3%B7%E2%8D%A826-'%24%25%268B%230469%40ADOPQRabdegopq'%E2%8D%B3%E2%8D%9E).

#### How it works

```
                                      ⍞ Read input.
          '$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq'⍳  Compute the indexes of the input characters
                                        in this string. Indexes are 1-based.
                                        26 == 'not found'
       26-                              Subtract each index from 26.
   20÷⍨                                 Divide those differences by 20.
  ⌈                                     Round up to the nearest integer.
+/                                      Add the results.
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 86

I/O via popup. Run the snippet in any <s>d</s>recent browser to test.

```js
for(c of prompt(t=0))c='$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq'.indexOf(c),~c?t+=1+(c<5):0;alert(t)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>96</s> <s>90</s> <s>75</s> 67+2 = 69 Bytes

Can't think of any other way to do this... is what I would have thought until I saw xnor's solution. I'll post what I had anyways.

*Thanks to FryAmTheEggman for saving 6 bytes*

Alright, now I'm happy with this.

*Thanks to xnor for the find trick, saving 4 bytes.*

Added two bytes since input needs to be enclosed in quotes.

```
print sum('#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq$%&8B'.find(x)/20+1for x in input())
```

Comment: I like the clever use of indexes! Also, python 3's a bit shorter because it uses input instead of raw_input.

Comment: @manatwork [It works fine in Python 2 with enclosing quotes..](http://i.imgur.com/QOMhsD9.png)

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I combined it with @DJMcMayhem's Python 3 comment.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 127 bytes

```
n;f(char*i){char*o="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq",*t="$%&8B";for(;*i;i++)if(strchr(o,*i))n++;else if(strchr(t,*i))n+=2;printf("%d",n);}
```

Pretty straightforward. Ungolfed version:

```
int num = 0;
void f(char* input)
{
    char *one="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq";
    char *two="$%&8B";

    for(;*input;input++)
        if(strchr(one, *input))     //If current character is found in first array
            num ++;
        else if(strchr(two, *input))//If cuurent character is found in second array
            num += 2;

    printf("%d", num);
}
```

**Test it [here](http://rextester.com/RKIC56361)**

If function arguments are not allowed, then the `stdin` version takes up to 141 bytes:

```
n;f(){char*o="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq",*t="$%&8B",i[99],*p;gets(i);for(p=i;*p;p++)if(strchr(o,*p))n++;else if(strchr(t,*p))n+=2;printf("%d",n);}
```

Note that the above version assumes that the input is atmost 98 characters long.

**Test it [here](http://rextester.com/OOLU87201)**

Command-line arguments version (143 bytes):

```
n;main(c,v)char**v;{char*o="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq",*t="$%&8B",*p=v[1];for(;*p;p++)if(strchr(o,*p))n++;else if(strchr(t,*p))n+=2;printf("%d",n);}
```

**Test it [here](http://rextester.com/INAN16332)**

Comment: @DJMcMayhem C is really not that bad. Try golfing in Fortran 77. ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 162

```java
class C{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(-a[0].length()+a[0].replaceAll("[#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq]","..").replaceAll("[$%&8B]","...").length());}}
```

Well if it *has* to be a full program... It's just a one-liner that matches characters and replaces them with a longer string. Then, returns the difference in length from the original. Unfortunately, java doesn't really have anything to just count the number of matches.

Here it is with line breaks:

```java
class C{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        System.out.print(
                -a[0].length() +
                a[0].replaceAll("[#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq]","..")
                .replaceAll("[$%&8B]","...")
                .length()
                        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - 35 bytes

Uses the obvious method of in first + *2 in second. Thanks @FryTheEggman.

```
s/Lz+"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq"*2"$%&8B
```

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2FLz%2B%22%230469%40ADOPQRabdegopq%22*2%22%24%25%268B&input=4+8+15+16+23+42&debug=1).

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, <s>114</s> 95 bytes

```
alert(prompt().replace(/[#046@ADOPQRabdegopq]/g,9).replace(/[$%&8B]/g,99).match‌​(/9/g).length)
```

Thanks to Ismael Miguel for helping me golf this.

Comment: 93 bytes: `alert(prompt().replace(/[#046@ADOPQRabdegopq]/g,9).replace(/[$%&8B]/g,99).match(/9/g).length)`

Comment: Sorry for counting badly. Yes, its 95.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 59 bytes

```
a=gets;p a.count('#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq')+2*a.count('$%&8B')
```

Input from command line or stdin. Shortest so far using a non-esoteric language.

Update: chilemagic beat me

Answer (score 3):

## J, 43

As a function:

```
   f=:[:+/[:,30$'$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq'=/]
   f 'text goes here'
6
```

## 46 bytes (command line)

As a standalone command-line program:

```
echo+/,30$'$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq'=/>{:ARGV
```

Save the above line as `counter2.ijs` and call from the command line:

```
$ jconsole counter2.ijs 'Programming Puzzles and Code Golf'
13
```

Comment: Copy-pasting the input into the code isn't allowed but a function which can take the input as an argument is ok. E.g. `f=:your_function_code`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 44 bytes

```
1

[#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq]
1
[$%&8B]
11
[^1]
<empty line>
```

Gives output in unary.

Each line should go to its own file or you can use the `-s` flag. E.g.:

```
> echo "pp&cg"|retina -s counter
11111
```

The pairs of lines (pattern - substitute pairs) do the following substitution steps:

- Remove `1`'s
- Substitute 1-counter letters with `1`
- Substitute 2-counter letters with `11`
- Remove everything but the `1`'s

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```matlab
t=readline();length(join(t∩"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq")*join(t∩"\$%&8B")^2)
```

This reads text from STDIN and prints the result to STDOUT.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
# Read text from STDIN
t = readline()

# Print (implied) to STDOUT the length of the intersection of t with the
# 1-closed counter list joined with the duplicated intersection of t with
# the 2-closed counter list
length(join(t ∩ "#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq") * join(t ∩ "\$%&8B")^2)
```

Example:

```matlab
julia> t=readline();length(join(t∩"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq")*join(t∩"\$%&8B")^2)
Programming Puzzles and Code Golf
13
```

Answer (score 2):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 56 bytes

```
_/
[#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq]/_
[$%&8B]/__
[^_]/
(_+)/(^^\1)
```

[Live demo.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=_%2F%0A%5B%230469%40ADOPQRabdegopq%5D%2F_%0A%5B%24%25%268B%5D%2F__%0A%5B%5E_%5D%2F%0A(_%2B)%2F(%5E%5E%5C1)&input=Programming%20Puzzles%20and%20Code-Golf%0A4%208%2015%2016%2023%2042%0AAll%20your%20base%20are%20belong%20to%20us%20%0AStandard%20loopholes%20apply%0AShortest%20answer%20in%20bytes%20is%20the%20winner!)

Comment: Just an fyi: I created a stub esolangs page for rs. You may wish to add to it: http://esolangs.org/wiki/Rs

Comment: @mbomb007 WOW!! That just made my day. :D

Comment: Well, "rs" doesn't come up in Google or anything since it's only two letters. This way, people can find it. :)

Answer (score 2):

GNU APL, 37 characters

```
+/,⍞∘.=30⍴'$%&8B#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq'
```

construct a character vector which contains 2-counter characters twice (30⍴)

compare each input char with every character in the vector (∘.=)

sum up ravelled matches (+/,)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript <s>159</s>, 130 Bytes

```
function c(b){return b.split("").map(function(a){return-1!="$%&8B".indexOf(a)?2:-1!="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq".indexOf(a)?1:0}).reduce(function(a,b){return a+b})};
```

unminified:

```
function c(b) {
    return b.split("").map(function(a) {
        return -1 != "$%&8B".indexOf(a) ? 2 : -1 != "#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq".indexOf(a) ? 1 : 0
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b
    })
};
```

With the help of @edc65:

```
function c(b){return b.split('').reduce(function(t,a){return t+(~"$%&8B".indexOf(a)?2:~"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq".indexOf(a)?1:0)},0)}
```

Comment: As `~ -1 == 0`, you can write `~x?` instead of `-1 != x?`. See me answer for an example of use.

Comment: `function c(b){return b.split('').reduce(function(t,a){return t+(~"$%&8B".indexOf(a)?2:~"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq".indexOf(a)?1:0)},0)}` No need to have `map` then `reduce`

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 117

```
a="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq"
b="$%&8B"
c n[]=n
c n(x:s)
 |e a=f 1
 |e b=f 2
 |True=f 0
 where
 e y=x`elem`y
 f y=c(n+y)s
```

c is a function `c :: Int -> String -> Int` which takes a counter and a string and goes through the string one letter at a time checking if the current letter is a member of the 1 point array or the 2 point array and calls itself for the rest of the string after incrementing the counter the appropriate amount.

Call with counter = 0 in ghci:

```
ghci> c 0 "All your base are belong to us"
12
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 157

```
void Main(string s){int v=0;v=s.ToCharArray().Count(c=>{return "#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq".Contains(c)||"$%&8B".Contains(c)?++v is int:false;});Console.Write(v);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
void Main(string s)
{
    int v = 0;

    v = s.ToCharArray()
    .Count(c => 
    {
        return "#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq".Contains(c) || "$%&8B".Contains(c) ? ++v is int:false;
    });

    Console.Write(v);
}
```

Converting the string into a char array, then seeing if each char is in either counter. If it is in the second one, I just have it incrementing the counter again.

Answer (score 1):

## Erlang, 103 bytes

This is a complete program that runs using escript. The first line of the file must be blank (adding 1 byte).

```
main([L])->io:write(c(L,"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq")+2*c(L,"$%&8B")).
c(L,S)->length([X||X<-L,S--[X]/=S]).
```

Sample run:

```
$ escript closed.erl 'Shortest answer in bytes is the winner!'
8$
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, c(L,"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq")+2*c(L,"$%&8B") is longer than c(L,"#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq$%&8B$%&8B") by 5 bytes :).

Comment: @Katyenko, thanks for the suggestion. Regrettably it doesn't work correctly for certain inputs. "$%&8B" counts for 5, but should be 10. The c/2 function works by filtering out the chars of the string that do not belong to a set of chars, such as "$%&8B". It checks for set inclusion by deleting the char to be tested from the set, then comparing the result with the original set. If they are not equal, then the char was in the set, and it is included. Multiple copies of chars in the set don't have any effect.

Comment: Ho, I see, I don't know erlang, was thinking you were using a string to count the counter :3. Anyway, nevermind, and well done :)

Answer (score 0):

## C, 99 bytes

```c
n;f(char*i){for(char*o="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq$%&8B",*t=o+20;*i;)n+=2-!strchr(o,*i)-!strchr(t,*i++);}
```

## Explanation

I further golfed [the answer of Cool Guy](/a/51923/39490); it got too long to be a comment.  Instead of the `if`/`else`, I took advantage of `!` converting a pointer to bool.  I also made `o` include `t` so that I could add "is in `o`" and "is in `t`" for the total number of counters.

## Expanded code

```c
#include <string.h>
int num = 0;

void f(char* input)
{
    char *one = "#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq"  "$%&8B";
    char *two = strchr(one, '$');

    while (*input) {
        num += 2 - !strchr(one, *input) - !strchr(two, *input));
        ++input;
    }
}
```

Output is in `num`, which must be cleared before each call.

## Test program and results

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const char* a[] = {
        "Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf",
        "4 8 15 16 23 42",
        "All your base are belong to us",
        "Standard loopholes apply",
        "Shortest answer in bytes is the winner!",
        NULL
    };
    for (const char** p = a;  *p;  ++p) {
        n=0;f(*p);
        printf("%3d: %s\n", n, *p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
 13: Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf
  5: 4 8 15 16 23 42
 12: All your base are belong to us
 12: Standard loopholes apply
  8: Shortest answer in bytes is the winner!
 37: n;f(char*i){for(char*o="#0469@ADOPQRabdegopq$%&8B",*t=o+20;*i;)n+=2-!strchr(o,*i)-!strchr(t,*i++);}
```

The code itself contains 37 counters by its own metric.