# Boxed character regions

Tags: code-golf, string

Given an input string, determine the number of regions that a page will be split into.

Consider the letter `P`. It has one enclosed region within the letter. Assume that each letter splits the page by one or more regions (i.e. a box is drawn around the character).

### Input

A string of 0 or more characters. You may assume that the string contains only characters from the following sets:

- +0 regions: Spaces , tabs `\t`, and new lines `\n`
- +1 region: `CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZcfhijklmnrstuvwxyz12357~!^*()-_=+[]{}\'|:;",.?/<>`
- +2 regions:`ADOPQRabdeopq469@#`
- +3 regions: `Bg08$%&`

You may take the input as a function argument, standard input, command-line argument, whatever works best for your language.

### Output

An integer representing the number of regions split by the given input. Output can be a return value or standard output (but not stderr).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest solution in bytes win.

### Test cases

- (empty string or only whitespace) === 1
- `-1` === 3
- `100%` === 11
- `Hello world!` === 16
- `May the force be with you` === 28
- `do {$busTickets-=2;} while ($transit != false)` === 54
- `return @$_GET['foo'] ?? $$var % $var || $g8 << ; //# Syntax error` === 80

Feel free to use the demo in my JavaScript answer (with a compatible browser of course) to run test cases.

### Visual representation

Note: The visual representation for the characters `g` and `0` (zero) may not be entirely correct depending on the monospaced font that your computer has installed.

For the purposes of this challenge, assume that the bottom of the `g` has a closed loop and the `0` has a slash through it.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  [
    'CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZcfhijklmnrstuvwxyz12357~!^*()-_=+[]{}\\\'|:;"<,>.?/`',
    'ADOPQRabdeopq469@#',
    'Bg08$%&'
  ].forEach(function(set, i) {
    set.split('').sort().forEach(function(letter) {
      var p = document.querySelectorAll('section[data-letter-regions="' + (i + 1) + '"]')[0];
      console.log(p)
      var el = document.createElement('span');
      el.setAttribute('class', 'letter');
      el.textContent = letter;
      p.appendChild(el);
    });
  });

}());
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
section + section {
  border-top: medium solid purple;
}
.letter {
  font-family: Consolas, 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<section data-letter-regions=1>
  <h1>1 region</h1>
</section>
<section data-letter-regions=2>
  <h1>2 regions</h1>
</section>
<section data-letter-regions=3>
  <h1>3 regions</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51877/counter-counter) I would even say duplicate.

Comment: @randomra Darn it... didn't come up when I searched for "letters" or "characters". Oh well, back to the drawing board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), 94 bytes

```js
f=x=>[...x].reduce((p,z)=>p+!!z.trim()+2*/[Bg08$%&]/.test(z)+/[ADOPQRabdeopq469@#]/.test(z),1)
```

#### Demo

As the code is in ES6, the demo only works in ES6-compatible browsers. At time of writing, this includes Firefox, Edge, and Chrome/Opera with experimental JavaScript features enabled.

```js
f = x => [...x].reduce((p, z) => p + !!z.trim() + 2 * /[Bg08$%&]/.test(z) + /[ADOPQRabdeopq469@#]/.test(z), 1)

// Snippet stuff
var v = function() {document.getElementById('Z').textContent = f(this.value)};
document.getElementById('I').addEventListener('keyup', v, false);
document.getElementById('I').addEventListener('change', v, false);
```

```css
textarea {width: 100%}
```

```html
<p><label>Input: <textarea id=I></textarea></label></p>

<p>Output: <output id=Z>1</output></p>
```